# ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 in joined table

Tags: mysql, join

I've been trying to figure this one out for a long time but am starting to give up.

To simplify the case, let's say I've got 2 tables. Main table is `articles` and I'm left joining it with `contracts`. The contracts table has an end date. **I only want to pick 1 (one) row from here per article, selecting the latest** `contract_to` **date.**

I've tried tried something like `LEFT JOIN contracts ON (contracts.article = articles.id) ORDER BY contract_to DESC LIMIT 1` but obviously it's not working.

How do I go about doing this?

Please pretend that the date ranges on each row in the contracts table below are different.
Also the latest date is not the same for all article contracts, so I can't just determine what the latest date is and then stick it into a WHERE clause.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the latest `contract_to` value, you'll need a `MAX()` aggregate. The proper way to do this is to use a subquery join to get only the `article` and `MAX(contract_to)` values, then join that with the remaining values of the row.  Finally, that whole structure can be joined against the `articles` table.

```
SELECT
  articles.*,
  contracts.*
FROM 
  articles
  /* Join against a subquery which returns only the article and latest contract_to */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT article, MAX(contract_to) AS contract_to
    FROM contracts
    GROUP BY article
  ) maxcontract ON articles.article_id = maxcontract.article
  /* and join that against the rest of the contracts table, on those two column values */
  JOIN contracts 
    ON maxcontract.article = contracts.article
    AND maxcontract.contract_to = contracts.contract_to
```

Since MySQL is lenient about the contents of the `GROUP BY` clause, this method may not actually be necessary, joining separately against the `contracts` table, and you could probably do it with the subquery join alone, but that won't work in most other RDBMS and this is really the right way to do it without relying on MySQL's weird behavior.

Comment: Tried this and getting error, "Unknown column `maxcontract.article` in ON clause". Did the alias not work?

Comment: @silkfire I had one of them as `maxcontracts` instead of `maxcontract`

Comment: I have 16,366 rows in the contracts table. The result I'm getting returns about 6000 rows. Something's wrong... At the moment I only have one date per article and region (yes, that's an extra dimension), but I will have more in the future.

Comment: @silkfire If there's an additional region dimension, that will require grouping and returning in the `SELECT` list from the `maxcontract` subquery, then also adding the corresponding condition to the `ON` clause with `contracts.

Comment: @silkfire Without a full table structure I can only speculate further. Given the information we have, this query ought to work.

Comment: Do you know why SO strips the '@Michael Berkowski' for some reason?
Okay, do I need to add it in the `SELECT article, regional_municipality, MAX(contract_to) AS contract_to` as well as `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Seems to be working now. The query is slow because I have `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` after the initial SELECT, without it it's really fast. But I need it for pagination purpose.

Comment: @silkfire I'm surprised it is that much slower without `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. I'm assuming there's a `WHERE` clause in there somewhere. You might be able to do a cartesian join against another subquery which returns only the aggregate `COUNT()` over the same set.

Comment: It's faster without, not slower. Cartesian JOIN? I have an extra query after this one just to retrieve the single value of how many rows the query returns ***without*** a LIMIT clause (`SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`).

Comment: @silkfire I meant slower _with_ `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  It shouldn't make a big difference. What is your `WHERE` clause against the `articles` table?

Comment: I only have a WHERE clause that retrieves all contracts that are >= CURDATE(). But removing this where clause makes no difference performance wise. I just want to know if I have to accept 1 sec queries (instead of 0.003 sec) in my project :)

Comment: @silkfire You may be able to join against `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT article) FROM contacts WHERE contract_to >= CURDATE())` to optimize the count on the only table where it actually is affected, (unless the `LEFT JOIN` is actually needed).  Join on it with no `ON` clause, add it to the outer `SELECT` list, and it will return a column with the same value for each row, and may be faster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35677/discussion-between-silkfire-and-michael-berkowski)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have the nice analytic functions that some DBMSes offer for this, but you could write (for example):

```
SELECT ...
  FROM articles
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT article,
                MAX(contract_to) AS contract_to
           FROM contracts
          GROUP
             BY article
       ) articles_to_max_contracts
    ON articles_to_max_contracts.article = articles.id
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN contracts
    ON contracts.article = articles.id
   AND contracts.contract_to = articles_to_max_contracts.contract_to
;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the price, you can also do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select price
        from contracts c
        where a.article = c.article
        order by contract_from desc
        limit 1
       ) as lastPrice
from articles a;
```

With an index on `contracts(article, contract_from)` this should even be relatively efficient.

Comment: Just tried that and query took 12 sec when it normally takes 0,3 sec (which is pretty slow as well).

Comment: @silkfire . . . Is that with the index?

Comment: That is with the index, yes =/